# How to inject the value from claim to data transfer object in asp net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

For example:
I have a dto as an action parameter with from body attribute

```
public IActionResult Bar([FromBody]Foo dto)
{
  var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
  var uid = Convert.ToInt32(claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value);
  dto.uid = uid;
  _barService(dto);
  return Ok();           
}
public class Foo
{
  public int uid {get;set;} // from claim
  public string something{get;set;} // from front end request
}
```

Currently,I have the write code to provide the claim value to the dto manually

**Q: In asp net core, how can I inject the claim value to the dto automatically?**

Comment: unclear what you are asking, the code seems fine.
What is your issue?

Comment: @Dementic I am using jwt to authorize the webapi,when there is a request, i can extract the user id from the jwt.I don`t want to assign the user id to the dto manually,when there is a request, i want the user id  in the dto assigned automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want duplicate code in your controllers you can put the code in a service or helper method or action filter.

For example:

```
public class FillDtoClaimAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = context.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var uid = Convert.ToInt32(claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value);
        ((Foo)context.ActionArguments["dto"]).uid = uid;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[FillDtoClaim]
public IActionResult Bar([FromBody]Foo dto)
{
    _barService(dto);
    return Ok();           
}
```